# Why the Visual-Studio development server auto-assigns the port number?

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio

What is the main reason for Visual-Studio to assign (auto-assign) a new port number to the development server?

Comment: You know this is something you can change in the project properties, right?

Comment: One question before I have learnt that! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using a random port way above the so-called [well-known ports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) there'll be less change for the port to be in use by another application.

Visual Studio randomizes the port on project creation:

> By default, when you create a Web site or a Web application project in Visual Studio that uses IIS Express or the Visual Studio Development Server, a port is selected for the project.

But if the port is in use when starting to debug the project, it'll auto-assign a new random, free port.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178109%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) how to alter this behaviour and manually assign a static port number.

Comment: I think that is badly phrased. Using a random port doesn't guarantee it will be free. Being able to choose from any port is what allows it to find one free. A random choice of port could still select one that is in use.

Comment: Sorry to correct again but in my experience if the port number becomes in use next time you enter debug it will choose a new one. At least it does on mine. I get this occasionally I think if VS crashes and leave the dev server running and when  inext debug I find I'm on a different port. :) Your general statement is sound though on the why. :)

Comment: The auto-assigned port for the Visual Studio Development Server is stored in the .csproj file on creation of the project and doesn't change after that (not when starting/stopping debugging, neither when restarting Visual Studio), so I doubt it's randomized on each debug. That also should conflict with the documentation. ;)

Comment: I didn't mean on each debug, I mean if it tries to start the dev server and the port is in use it will generate a new port. I don't think this disagrees with what you quoted above though. Anyway, just sharing my own experiences. I feel like I'm making a bit too big of a deal if it now. ;-)

Comment: Don't think that, I love to hear when I'm assuming something wrong. And you seem to be right, if the port is in use it'll auto-assing a new one. Answer updated (again). Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

Because if it didn't assign a port then it would use port 80 which wouldn't work for anyone with IIS / Apache / another web servier in its default configuration.

Seeing as its got to choose a port number, it just chooses one which is free at the point when the development web server is started.